# Can I use an Edit Mask to format output? (not just validate input)

Tags: delphi

Delphi 7 question. I'm working with a form that has many databound controls (changing this is not an option). I have a TDBEDIT control bound to a TStringField (which has a EditMask property). I know I can use this EditMask to force the control to validate its input, but what I want to know is if I can populate the field directly with the raw value and have the control display it according to the EditMask?

I want to populate the field with a 16 digit number, but I want it displayed as 4 lots of 4 digits (ie. 9999 9999 9999 9999).

If I do ...

```
dbedtABCNumber.DataSource.DataSet.Edit;
dbedtABCNumber.Field.Value := '1234567812345678';
```

I only get the first 4 digits displayed.

I hope there's someone out there who's more familiar with the intracacies of old databound controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [TField.OnGetText event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TField_OnGetText.html) or [TNumericField.DisplayFormat property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TNumericField_DisplayFormat.html) to modify how the text is being displayed.

Since you have a TStringField holding numbers, you have two choices:

- use a `TNumericField` and the `DisplayFormat` property
- use the `OnGetText` event and do your own string formatting

***Edit:***

Sam used this approach:

*I implemented `OnSetText` and `OnGetText` event handlers. I already had the `Edit Mask` `9999 9999 9999 9999;1;_` so the `OnSetText` was just*

```
TStringField(Sender).Value := Trim(Text);
```

*and `OnGetText` was just*

```
sValue := TStringField(Sender).Value;  
Text := Format('%s %s %s %s', [Copy(sValue, 1, 4), Copy(sValue, 5, 4), Copy(sValue, 9, 4), Copy(sValue, 13, 4)]);
```

*It works fine. Thanks.*

Comment: @Sam: which one did you choose?

Comment: I implemented OnSetText and OnGetText event handlers. I already had the Edit Mask 9999 9999 9999 9999;1;_ so the OnSetText was just TStringField(Sender).Value := Trim(Text); and OnGetText was just sValue := TStringField(Sender).Value;
Text := Format('%s %s %s %s', [Copy(sValue, 0, 4), Copy(sValue, 4, 4), Copy(sValue, 8, 4), Copy(sValue, 12, 4)]); It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeroen, actually the string indexes need to be adjusted... Text := Format('%s %s %s %s', [Copy(sValue, 0, 4), Copy(sValue, 5, 4), Copy(sValue, 9, 4), Copy(sValue, 13, 4)]);

Comment: @Sam: I made that a ... 1, 4 as well as strings are 1-based.